# WPF highliting treeview row at mouse hover.

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a question about how can I highlight only one row at mouse hover event in treeview.
I've added trigger

```
     <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"></Condition>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"></Setter>
     </MultiTrigger>
```

But I get the following result:

Here pic:https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9N3x.png

As you can see that parents of each item is highlighted also. In this example - mouse was over TempPE item.

Comment: Have you tried to add a trigger when `IsMouseOver` is false to set the `Background` of Bd to transparent?

Comment: Thanks, for response, but it didn't help, unfortunatelly.

Comment: I found solution. SourceName should be added to condition:          <Condition SourceName="Bd" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"></Condition>